# Does autodesk forge support downloading as an ascii fbx

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Does Autodesk Forge support downloading an fbx in ascii format? Is there a list somewhere of currently supported derivative formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the list of supported output formats here:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/

As of now fbx output is not supported yet.